How do I fix the 'ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED' error after deploying my ASP.NET MVC application?
After publishing my application in the VM's IIS, I added the IP address in the hosts file, added port 81 to inbound rules. However, when I try to open the website outside of the VM and my pc, I get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED issue when I try to open the website to other PC's (those machines at work).
How can I fix the error? 


Can you run a report and see what it says? https://docs.lextudio.com/jexusmanager/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html

There are many reasons for this error, you can try this solution:
In registry, at path:
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters
it was having 2 values removed the second one, left the default one.

there is only one which is the default one.

I suggest you could also use network monitor to see what happen when you send the request from the outside VM to the server. It seems that your route server or your application server refused connection. Details about how to use network monitor, you could refer to this article.
